# greycomatrix in python including NaN's

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, glcm

I have an irregular region of interest from an MRI image which I have selected. I would like to do co-occurrence analysis on the image using `skimage.feature.greycomatrix` library. However, my ROI is irregular in shape. Keeping 0's in the numpy array of the image would result in an incorrect grey co-occurrence analysis and I have made them `NaN`'s. However, the `greycomatrix` is unable of analyzing a numpy array with `NaN`'s. Has anyone experienced this problem or have a solution?

Comment: I don't think *python* itself has `greycomatrix`.  Do you mean [`skimage.feature.graycomatrix` from `sckit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_glcm.html)?  If not, which image processing library are you currently getting the function from?

Comment: Hi Warren, yes I am importing skimage.feature.greycomatrix. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to use this library on images which include NaN's/irregular ROIs or if there is another greycomatrix library that can be used. I remember reading that matlab can handle NaN's in the calculations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to this question, it doesn't seem as if the greycomatrix library in skimage can handle NaN values or irregular shapes but only does 'whole-image' analysis.

To get past this, I chose to do the image analysis in 'R' by exporting the matrix as a csv then importing it in R using:

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
ro.r("Axial_Data <- read.csv('axial_slice_ROI.csv', header = FALSE)")
print(ro.r('max(Axial_Data, na.rm = TRUE)'))
ro.r('Axial_Data <- as.matrix(Axial_Data)')
ro.r("library(radiomics)")
ro.r("library('glcm')") 
ro.r("library('raster')")

## get first order statistics
ro.r("first_order <- calc_features(Slice_Data)")
## GLCM
ro.r("textures <- glcm(raster(Axial_Data), na_opt = 'any', shift=list(c(0,1),c(1,1), c(1,0), c(1,-1)))")
```

Hope that helps anyone who may have similar issues in the future.

Cheers,